# Upgrade to 13.04. Dell Laptop fan running excessivly

Tags: 13.04, dell, fan

I recently updated to Ubuntu 13.04 on a Dell laptop. I did not have this problem with the previous version.

Normally the fan is not running. But then something (perhaps some web site) triggers the system to turn on the fan at high (and noisy) speed. It does not return to normal on its own, if I put the system to sleep, the fan turns off, until something triggers it again.

Machine is a Dell D420. CPU is a U2500 Core Duo @ 1.20 GHz. GPU is an Intel® 945GM.
Installing TLP with no configuration changes reduces the fan sped and noise, but kills GUI performance.

How can I diagnose this? I want to know if it is a driver issue (other posts mention graphics drivers) or a firefox bug?

Comment: which dell laptop model ....

Comment: It's a Dell D420. CPU is a U2500 Core Duo @ 1.20 GHz. Graphics is via an Intel® 945GM.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/301804/do-i-need-intel-linux-graphics-installer/301825#301825

Comment: Install TLP and Configure it , and also install Intel Drivers...and update me with tlp-stat

Comment: TLP seems to have resolved the fan issue. I just installed it, I did not do any configuration.

Answer (score 1):

for automatically controlling the fan, it is just to use 'i8kmon' inside the package i8kutils.

The latest version of i8kutils is at https://launchpad.net/i8kutils

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer at [Dell Laptop Fan Control](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/controlling-dell-fan-speeds-temperature-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/)

Solution for a Dell laptop is to install the i8kutils package.

*i8kutils - utilities for Dell Inspiron and Latitude laptops*

sudo apt-get install i8kutils

In my case I ran **i8kctl fan - 1** which cut down the right side fan to normal speed.