# Do I need Intel Linux Graphics Installer?

Tags: 13.04, intel-graphics

I am using 64 bit ubuntu 13.04 on a system running optimus technology - Nvidia 635M and an intel integrated card.

Recently came across this article for Intel Linux Graphics Installer:
http://networkedblogs.com/LHlmO

Now I am wondering if I need this installed? If yes, then would also like to know what graphics drivers are currently running the intel card on my system then?

---

**UPDATE** -
Per Qasim's response tried installing, but even after adding the two keys provided on their website, Software Center gives me the below warning:

> Lintian check results for /home/charlie/Downloads/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.1_amd64.deb:
>   perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
>   perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
>       LANGUAGE = (unset),
>       LC_ALL = (unset),
>       LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
>       are supported and installed on your system.
>   perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
>   E: intel-linux-graphics-installer: malformed-deb-archive found 4 members instead of 3

Let me know why am getting this message and what it means?

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: @Qasim I ran the command (what was it supposed to do?) but still get the same message

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f > it will install dependencies for a program if needed, sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade > it will update & upgrade packages, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  > it will also upgrade packages

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346581

Comment: I tried all the hints and methods i could find in the above link, but to no avail :( Sadly the previous warnings mentioned in the question are still displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to install **Intel Graphic Driver**

> The question is why ?

The answer is

1. It has  Intel Hardware Acceleration For Intel **3D ( VA-API )**.
2. ( VA-API ) also save battery power, I have done lots of testing so i will recommend to install Intel drivers. https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads
3. For Vmware user's 3D acceleration is **ON** by default and you don't need to do any tweaks for 3D acceleration

You check full details on ( VA-API ) on my answer, You can install it manually check my answer [VA-API (Hardware Acceleration For Intel / AMD GPUs)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681), **But intel drivers updated VA-API package.**

Comment: Thanks! but i still am not sure, if my current setup does not have these drivers, then what is driving the intel chip graphics? Or is it that 3D acceleration is not being used on intel chip because i dont have this installed?

Comment: The current setup has Intel drivers ..not the updated one