# What is the difference between the 2013Q1 Intel Linux Graphics Stack Release and xserver-xorg-video-intel?

Tags: installation, drivers, upgrade, graphics, intel-graphics

Webup8 recently posted a description on how to [upgrade your intel graphics driver](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/intel-linux-graphics-installer.html) to the "2013Q1 Intel Linux Graphics Stack Release". I already have `xserver-xorg-video-intel` installed from the main raring repositories. What is the difference between the two packages?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/301804/do-i-need-intel-linux-graphics-installer/301825#301825

Comment: @Qasim thanks for the link. So is 2013Q1 Intel Linux Graphics Stack Release just a more-recent version of xserver-xorg-video-intel?

Comment: i have tested the most recent one... so my recommendation are to install ...Released: 20 May 2013 , Version: 1.0.1

Comment: @Qasim Sorry, perhaps I was unclear in my question. Are you saying that "2013Q1 Intel Linux Graphics Stack Release" and `xserver-xorg-video-intel` are exactly the same thing, but just different versions? (This is essentially my question, which does differ slightly to the link, so feel free to post it as an answer.)

Comment: It has the same version with extra libraries ...

Answer (score 1):

the difference between them is that the 2013Q1 stack breaks 13.04(raring). after the install ubuntu would only boot into "low graphics mode" no matter if i was using lightdm or gdm.

using the "intel open installer" v1.0.1 and the intel open source repos i get this lovely distro update and suddenly the old xserver/plymouth "race" bug is back
(launchpad bug #982889). after checking a LOT of forums it appears the workaround is

insert this line

"sleep 10"

in /etc/init/lightdm.conf

just before the line

"exec lightdm"

i didn't have to add stuff to (or even create) /etc/X11/xorg.conf and i also didn't need to purge/install lightdm, unity-greeter, ubuntu desktop, the X server or any of the other carry on - i DID try all those options but they failed to fix the problem - the "sleep 10" fixed it for me.

it was odd - because the x logs showed everything being detected just fine and then boom - low graphics mode.

maybe the intel boys and the ubuntu people need some better cross-communication??

it appears that the kernel modules in the intel open source repo(s) don't have the plymouth/X fix installed on them.

after the graphics stack upgrade i'm now running 13.04 raring and 3.8.0-26 generic kernel x86_64