# 14.04: What to do about deprecated Intel Linux Graphics installer?

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics

After Intel deprecated its graphics installer in [version 0.8](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/03/latest-intel-linux-graphics-drivers-now-available-for-ubuntu-14-10), but some people [recommending](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301804/do-i-need-intel-linux-graphics-installer) the use of the Intel Graphics Installer, what can I do?

Comment: Do not use the installer on 14.04, use drivers from repository. If you really need fresh drivers in 14.04, take a look at the x-org edgers ppa (https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), they got it all. But be warned: bleeding edge may contain unwanted bugs.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly:

You have 3 choices, do nothing, upgrade Ubuntu to a version that the intel installer supports, or run another distro that the installer supports.

To help in choosing:

The big reason for an LTS release is to have an OS that is stable and does not change often.
If having the latest graphics is important you should consider following the latest Ubuntu releases instead of LTS.
A question you need to answer yourself is does 14.04 LTS and the latest Intel installer for it lack anything you need, will 14.10 and the updated drivers give you anything you desire ?
Don't assume having the latest features is always better, as you may end up with bugs/issues and features you never use/need.

Comment: I thought the advantage would be similar to the use of proprietary driver of, let's say, NVIDIA? expecially with my recent Thinkpad T440s I assumed a better use of the chipset as well?